# Click listener for multiple buttons ive created dynamically Android Studio

Tags: java, android, events, button, click

Okay so I am making an android application, and I have a list of goals let's say to make it easy to explain. A goal consists of a string. This data will be coming from a database so in the future, the length of the list may be slightly longer or slightly shorter. Each goal is placed inside the text of a button.

I have made this loop to create the buttons at run time due to the changing length of the list depending on whats happened before and this all works perfectly, i can create the buttons and they are placed where i want etc. This is the code I used to do this.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < goals.size(); i++){
        buttons[i] = new Button(this.getContext());
        buttons[i].setLayoutParams(params);
        buttons[i].setPadding(0,150,0,150);
        buttons[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        buttons[i].setText(goals.get(i));
        buttons[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_back);
        buttons[i].setTextSize(30);
        buttons[i].setTransformationMethod(null);
        linear.addView(buttons[i]);
    }
```

Now my issue is I want the click of each button to do a slightly different thing - depending on the goal ie, the text of the button. I really am struggling with setting up the click event so that different buttons will do different things even tho i have created all of them dynamically.

I can give more detail into the setup I am in in the android studio, but I feel I've given enough insight into my issue.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Why not using ListView or RecyclerView ?

Comment: I am down for the comment above, you might consider using something that optimizes and holds all that list of buttons, and you can create a 'click' listener that, through the adapter, specifies the behavior for each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that if you already know what the function of each button should be according to the text, couldn't you just take the text of the button and then use it in switch (or something else) to get specific functionality like:

```
buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View view){

       //Put whatever is common between buttons outside of the switch

       switch(((Button)view).getText().toString()){

       //And then just assign a case for whatever functionality you need specifically for each goal

       }

   }


});
```